# Not Eligible to participate

Tags: venomblockchain

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcHqL.jpg)

In the criteria we need 22 NFT to pass the requirement to receive NFT as a reward but I am not still eligible to participate? what happend?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrIcZ.jpg)

I have 22 NFT testnet but did not receive the reward NFT